# Offline compression (django_compressor app) error after django upgrade

Tags: django, django-compressor

I just upgrade Django 1.4.2 to 1.5 and I started to get an error on **django_compressor**.

```
You have offline compression enabled but key "eb225276268ea55d3b90c71df63109d9" is missing from offline manifest. You may need to run "python manage.py compress".
```

Also, I updated django_compressor to the last version (actual 1.2), and still getting the same error.

When I try `python manage.py compress` I am noticed that:

```
c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\hashcompat.py:9: DeprecationWarning: django.utils.hashcompat is deprecated; use hashlib instead DeprecationWarning)
```

Is this notice related with the offline compression error?

**[UPDATED]**
I am finding another interesting thing...

In the template that I am having problem I removed all css that should be compressed:

```
 {% extends "base.html" %}
    {%  block head %}
        {% load compress %}
        {% compress css %}

        {% endcompress %}
    {% endblock %}
...
```

I ran python manage:

```
python manage.py compress 
python manage.py collectstatic   --noinput
```

without errors.

But... The problem still happen.

```
You have offline compression enabled but key "e764a8b7e7e314ed8c98aa5d25fc76b4" is missing from offline manifest. You may need to run "python manage.py compress".
1   {% extends "base.html" %}
2   {% block head %}
3   {% load compress %}
4   {% compress css %}
5   
6   {% endcompress %}
7   {% endblock %}
8
```

Another important information: the .html file was listed when I ran `python manage.py compress`

Comment: https://github.com/jezdez/django_compressor/issues/131

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I had to remove all `{% load compress %}` block from the internal pages, and included every js and css in the base.html. Now it worked. But I still finding very strange that this issue just happened after django update.

Comment: Can you provide more information on this? I'm having this issue on my index.html, but all my `js` and `cs` information is already there...

Comment: @KVISH Have you got any solution ? I am facing same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, i tried every possible solution that i found in internet, but in vain every time i run python manage.py compress i used to get the same error.

At last i thought instead of finding solution's why don't i debug by reading compress.py (the path of the file was there in the error console), by doing this i figured out that there were compress tags inside compress tag.

{% compress js%}
  {% compress js%}

{% endcompress %}

{% endcompress %}

So the key was always not their in the manifest.json file.

Answer (score -1):

No.

The error is telling you that, although you have offline compression enabled, the process has never been run, or the cache is empty.

Basically, if you tell compressor NOT to try to compress files on every HTTP request (offline compression), it will look to Django's cache system to find the path to the compressed version of your assets.

If offline compression is enabled, and it can't find the path to the files the cache says should be there, it freaks out.

Comment: But isn't strange that it just started to happen after Django update? The settings.py is the same.

Comment: Not really. Correlation isn't causality.

Comment: I reviewed my configuration from settings.py and I didnt find anything wrong. But take a look in a new information that I just posted.

Comment: This answer worked for me. I had cache set to LocalMemory, which will not work.
I set cache to FileBasedCache and then run compree, and it worked.
Reason here is that LocMemCache limits the stroage to current process. MemcachedCache or any other persistant cache will work.